# How to hit breakpoint in startup.cs for a program that is already running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an application that is always running on IIS, (the program is always deployed to IIS, and to update it you will need to rebuild the solution).

But I want to add a breakpoint on `startup.cs` for debugging purposes.

But since the app is already running I cannot hit the break point.
And if I want to rebuild the program then debugging mode will stop.

Are there any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: I'd normally just place an endless loop (with a sleep inside it) at the start of `Main`. Then once you attach the debugger, you can just move the execution beyond the loop and step through. What problem are you trying to solve though?

Comment: You can try [Debugger.Launch();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=net-6.0)

Comment: To build off of @MarkusMeyer if the Launch doesn't work, `Debugger.Break()` could also be a workaround, it will prompt you to select a debugger if you don't already have one selected. That being said, definitely try `Launch` before `Break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MS Docs: Debugger.Launch Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=net-6.0)

> Launches and attaches a debugger to the process.

```cs
Debugger.Launch();
```

As mentioned by @Ibrennan208, [Debugger.Break()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=net-6.0) might be a workaround if `Launch` does not work:

> To build off of @MarkusMeyer if the Launch doesn't work, Debugger.Break() could also be a workaround, it will prompt you to select a debugger if you don't already have one selected. That being said, definitely try Launch before Break.

> If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a debugger. If users say yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger breakpoint had been hit.